# Set variable with time to use as random

Tags: php, variables, random

If I set a variable as follows:

```
$randNum = md5(time());
```

and use that to create:

```
$tempFileName = $randNum.'_temp.'.$type;
```

and then, later in the script:

```
$newFileName = $randNum.'_new.'.$type;
```

Will it be generating a new random number the second time around or will `$randNum` value be the same as the 1st?

Comment: Are you using `$randNum = md5(time());` again after using it once ?

Comment: Same as the first if you don't call `$randNum = md5(time());` again

Comment: make a function that generates the random number and call the function over and over. For instance `function RandomNumber() { return md5(time()); }`, test case: `for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++) { echo RandomNumber(), "\n"; }`

Comment: If you think that this may produce two different numbers, you may be more interested in learning lazy languages like Haskell, in which this may actually work this way. Not so in classic imperative languages like PHP. Also, there's virtually no point in hashing the time value, you're not going to add any more entropy to it. You may as well be using the `time()` number as is.

Comment: it randomly changes its value, for no apparent reason. that's why it's called a variable. *</sarcasm>*

Comment: There's a race condition here. `time()` only has a granularity of 1 second. If the script is run twice in a second then the second time it's run it'll overwrite the files from the first.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath That is absolutely not why it is called a variable. It is called so because the contents of it can be varied by whoever or whatever wants to vary them. If all variables were random, coding would be a lot more freaking difficult!

Comment: Also keep in mind that using `time()` is not a good idea as it may chock with concurrent access, instead, use [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/uniqid)

Comment: I should have said, in my original script, I use a random number function, I was using `md5(time());` in the question to save time typing :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $randnum value will be the same as the first. If in doubt just test it:

```
$randNum = md5(time());
echo $randNum;
sleep(5);// sleep for 5 seconds
echo $randNum;
```

The values will be the same.

Comment: "Should"? You can change that to a *"must"*. If they're not the same, something is seriously wrong with your PHP. :)

Comment: I would say you *have to* change that to a must.

Comment: Yes, I've changed the wording. Thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$newFileName = $randNum.'_new.'.$type;
```

instead of

```
$newFileName == $randNum.'_new.'.$type;
```

output:

```
87bc7ff76220f988dd191bd804482bff_temp.
87bc7ff76220f988dd191bd804482bff_new.
```

Comment: sorry, typo in question. I'm not using `==` :)